# Is there a way to automatically find which files are compiled into a library using cmake/make?

Tags: c, makefile, cmake

I have a C library which I am using in a project. It consists of `.c` and `.h` files in `src` and `include` directories. I wrote a `CMakeLists.txt` file that generates a `Makefile` which compiles `library.so`.

The thing is, the library also includes `.c` files for tests, compatibility headers for other operating systems, and other files which I don't actually use. I would like to determine which src/header files are actually compiled into the `.so` library. Is there a way to do so automatically, based on `CMakeLists.txt` or `Makefile`, without going through and examining each file?

Comment: Does `get_target_property(LIB_SOURCES lib_target SOURCES)` do the job?

Comment: @kaylum That command only includes source `.c` files, neglecting headers.

Comment: That depends how your CMakeLists.txt is written. Which you haven't shown so can't provide further comment on that.

Comment: Make has the option `-n` to do a dry-run, that is printing all commands without actually executing them. This way you can see which modules will be compiled and linked. -- Compilers commonly have options to generate a listing that tells you which files were included. Some even print the files read. -- It's all about reading the documentation of your tools.

Comment: Not sure if this is possible for header files, but for sources when rebuilding from scratch all the .o files are listed on the command line output and there's one .o file per .c file. But for headers I'm pretty sure cmake does not execute a parser that could understand `#ifdef FOO #include <a/b.h> #else #include <c/d.h> #endif` especially since you're not required to list header files individually but you could just do a`target_include_directories`to some dir.However there may be compiler dependent options that could work;I know there exists one for VS; not sure if it can be set from cmake

Comment: Would be nice to know if my answer worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `gcc`then you can trick the compiler into telling you which source files it used by generating the dependency information for the next `make` run. If I am right, the necessary flags are:

```
-MT $@ -MMD -MP -MF $(AUTODEP_DIR)$(notdir $@).d
```

This should produce for `foo.cpp` a file `foo.o.d` which contains target-prerequisites lines like:

```
foo.o : foo.cpp bar.hpp baz.hpp
foo.cpp :
bar.hpp :
baz.hpp :
```

where the line with the object file as target (the file before the `:`) displays what got used as C/C++ source in the compile run (all files after the `:`). Starting with the list of `.o` files which are in the libary, this should give you the exact list of files that you are looking for. It requires a bit of scripting but doesn't look too complicated.

`clang` and other compilers of course have their own, maybe differing set of flags but it shouldn't be too hard to pick them.